# Angular Observable undefined despite being set in constructor and subscribed to correctly (using firebase)

Tags: angular, firebase, promise, observable

**My component error**: `ERROR TypeError: "this.brandService.getCurrentBrand(...) is undefined"`

The issue is the code inside the `this.auth.currentUser.then()` block of the BrandService constructor is not running prior to the component subscribing to it, thus the component is getting an undefined error.

My **component** is subscribing to a "currentBrand" Observable inside my BrandService:

```
  private currentBrand: Brand;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.brandService.getCurrentBrand().subscribe((brand) => {
      this.currentBrand = brand;
    });
  }
```

The **BrandService** is setting the "currentBrand" in the constructor and has the getCurrentBrand() method to return it:

```
  private currentBrand: Observable<Brand>;

  constructor(
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
    private auth: AngularFireAuth,
    private userService: UserService
  ) {
    this.brandsCollection = this.afs.collection('brands', (ref) =>
      ref.orderBy('name', 'asc')
    );

    this.auth.currentUser.then((authUser) => {
      console.log('this is logged prior to the undefined error');

      this.userService.getUserByEmail(authUser.email).then((user) => {
        console.log('for some reason, this is logged after the undefined error, need this to run prior to in order to eliminate the error');
        this.currentBrand = this.getBrand(user.defaultBrandId);
      });
    });
  }

  getCurrentBrand(): Observable<Brand> {
    return this.currentBrand;
  }

  getBrand(id: string): Observable<Brand> {
    this.brandDoc = this.afs.doc<Brand>(`brands/${id}`);

    this.brand = this.brandDoc.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map((action) => {
        if (action.payload.exists === false) {
          return null;
        } else {
          const data = action.payload.data() as Brand;
          data.id = action.payload.id;
          return data;
        }
      })
    );

    return this.brand;
  }
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I would think everything in the BrandService constructor should run prior to the component's ngOnInit and therefore this undefined error shouldn't be happening. I am correctly placing the code in the constuctor inside the .then() methods which is executed upon resolution of the Promises. I just can't seem to figure this one out...

Comment: can you add this.getBrand code.

Comment: @AakashGarg sure! adding now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make `currentBrand` a RxJS `BehaviorSubject`. This is a common case of mixing promises and observables. I am using RxJS `from` to convert promises to observables and map it using `switchMap` operator to finally make the (presumably HTTP) call in `this.getBrand()` method.

Try the following

```js
private currentBrand = new BehaviorSubject<Brand>(null);

constructor(
  private afs: AngularFirestore,
  private auth: AngularFireAuth,
  private userService: UserService
) {
  this.brandsCollection = this.afs.collection('brands', (ref) =>
    ref.orderBy('name', 'asc')
  );

  from(this.auth.currentUser).pipe(
    switchMap((authUser) => {
      console.log('this is logged prior to the undefined error');
      return from(this.userService.getUserByEmail(authUser.email)).pipe(
        switchMap((user) => {
          console.log('for some reason, this is logged after the undefined error, need this to run prior to in order to eliminate the error');
          return this.getBrand(user.defaultBrandId);
        })
      )
    })
  ).subscribe(
    response => {
      this.setCurrentBrand(response);      // <-- push the response to `currentBrand` observable here
    },
    error => {
      // handle error
    }
  );
}

getCurrentBrand(): Observable<Brand> {
  return this.currentBrand.asObservable();
}

setCurrentBrand(brand: Brand) {
  this.currentBrand.next(brand);
}
```

Component

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.brandService.getCurrentBrand().subscribe((brand) => {
    if (brand) {
      this.currentBrand = brand;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I believe this might work. I'm unfamiliar with BehaviorSubject. Any chance you could provide a setCurrentBrand() method for the BrandService?

Comment: With the `BehaviorSubject` you would be pushing the value using the `next` method. I've updated the answer to include a `setCurrentBrand()` method.

Comment: Thank you again. This has fixed my problem and better yet, explained why it happened. If I didn't mix Observables and Promises I assume it wouldn't have happened then. I appreciate that info and I will be mindful of that moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem you are facing is because your code executes asynchronously. I have tried to explain the problem inline.

```
    //When the instance of ur service get created this thing is undefined 
    private currentBrand: Observable<Brand>;

      constructor(
        private afs: AngularFirestore,
        private auth: AngularFireAuth,
        private userService: UserService
      ) {
        this.brandsCollection = this.afs.collection('brands', (ref) =>
          ref.orderBy('name', 'asc')
        );
        // this is async function which will take some time
        this.auth.currentUser.then((authUser) => {
          console.log('this is logged prior to the undefined error');
           // this again is async operation
          this.userService.getUserByEmail(authUser.email).then((user) => {
            console.log('for some reason, this is logged after the undefined error, need this to run prior to in order to eliminate the error');

            // ONCE ALL THE ASYNC OPERATION ARE DONE YOU ARE ASSINGING THE VALUE HERE
            this.currentBrand = this.getBrand(user.defaultBrandId);
          });
        });
      }
      // SO it will take some time to set value 
      //Till that time currentBrand will be undefined
      getCurrentBrand(): Observable<Brand> {
        return this.currentBrand;
  }
```

As inside your component you are trying to get its value in ngoninit method like given below
private currentBrand: Brand;

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.brandService.getCurrentBrand().subscribe((brand) => {
      this.currentBrand = brand;
    });
  }
```

`this.brandService.getCurrentBrand() /`/ this value will be undefined till the time all ur promises get resolved.

I hope you got the problem. Now the fix could be to make the  currentBrand as behavioursubject and do next on the inner promise then. like given below

```
currentBrand : =new BehaviourSubject(initial value);
```

inside ur promise do it like this.

```
currentBrand.next('value you get from ur promise' )
```